# asp.net mvc Controller - View logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to learn the asp.net mvc. I have worked with most of the samples that MS have published.

Most of the samples is just about CRUD.

I'm pretty good at working with webforms, but now I kind of miss the old easy world.

But, my question is: I have a detail page that is connected to an order, I have the order details comming along all well. I got my order detail lines kind of work. But now I would like to do different things with this order, like add more order lines, change the order status with a button, email the order and so on. In webforms I just added eventhandlers on the click event, but here... Do I need multiple forms? How do I make serverside code for example when someone wants to change the orderstatus with a click of a button?

Comment: :) I tried changing the title now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you go through the entire [NerdDinner](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) tutorial.
But to answer your question:
There really are no forms in asp.net MVC. There are views, which show your order, and there are controllers/actions which allow you to run code to generate views, update your database, etc. You ask if you need another form - the answer is No. You will, however, need at least a new action on a controller, and possibly a new view to confirm that the order was changed. An overview to a very simplified solution would be:

You want to allow an order to be marked as closed by clicking a button. Assume you have a controller called Order, and a view (in the order views folder) called Details. You'll have to add an action which takes an integer as a parameter to your order controller called "Close". In that action, you'll read the integer parameter (the order ID) and execute code to update that particular order to closed. You'll probably want to return the same view with the udpated status from this action. You'll have to add a link (probably using HTML.ActionLink function) to your view to call this new action.

Comment: The NerdDinner tutorial is for version 1.0, is it much different than 3.0?

Comment: There are quite a few improvements/enhancements from 1.0, to 3.0, but the core knowledge that you gain from the nerddinner tutorial will apply to any version. Honestly though, going through the tutorial rather than just viewing examples will seriously benefit you - especially if you are still asking about needing new forms.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i can recomend you [Pro ASP.NET MVC 2 Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865) book by Steven Sanderson

Comment: Thank you, I will order that book.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC everything is Post and Get actions. You can post to difference controllers. It seems you need to spent a bit more time reading about it. If you do not fancy reading - try some nice video tutorials for beginners. http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Well.. things have changed a lot since I added this post in 2011. I was moving from web forms that time. Now I have discovered the fantastic combination of angularJS and Web API :)